# PROC MIXED in SAS for mixed model

Tags: sas

I have a question about the REPEATED statement in PROC MIXED in SAS. If I don't add the RANDOM statement, the model wouldn't be a mixed model because there is no random effect?

Answer (score 2):

No. That is not right.  You can often make the same model using either REPEATED or RANDOM. This is a very confusing bit of SAS and they removed the confusion in GLIMMIX.  To tell what your model is, you should write it out in matrix form; a lot of hints to how to do this are in the details section of the MIXED documentation.